# What does "|| {}" mean at the start of a JavaScript file

Tags: javascript

I am looking at some JavaScript files. Some of them have something interesting at the beginning:

```
var something = something || {};
```

Where "something" is clearly a kind of varable name. What does this mean and what does it do? In fact, one file has this and nothing else.

Answer (score 6):

This is a common pattern to make sure a variable exists and if it does not, to set it to a known initial value so it can be used later. In particular:

- If the variable `something` already has a value that is not falsy, this line leaves the value of the variable unchanged.
- If this variable `something` does not have a value, or is falsy, this line sets the value of the variable to `{}`.

You will see this pattern a lot when adding properties to an object in a script. Let's say you worked for the company Acme and you had a lot of script files to integrate with other people's code. The `Acme` object would have a bunch of properties and a bunch of functions. In some scripts you might want to add properties to the object. But you can't just say

```
Acme.TIMEOUT = 300;
```

at the top of a file because the variable might not exist. But if it *does* exist, you want to use the existing variable. If it doesn't, you need to create a fresh object first.

So

```
var Acme = Acme || {};
```

will guarantee it exists, and then you can use it.

Be careful with this, though. I don't like this pattern because in modern JavaScript (where we use `let` and `const` instead of `var`), having an undefined variable will cause an error to be thrown. You should say:

```
window.Acme = window.Acme || {};
```

if you are in a browser. The reason for this is that it makes clear `Acme` is a property of the `window` object. Referencing a non-existent property of an object is harmless, you just get `undefined`. But referencing a non-existent variable will throw an error in modern JavaScript (or if not, it should).

Comment: `var Acme = Acme || {};` will not throw an error. The `Acme` variable is guaranteed to exist on account of it having `var` before it.

Comment: Totally correct, and thank you. It fails with `let` and `const`. And IMHO it would be a shame to use this pattern just to take advantage of `var`'s highly permissive semantics. While var _does_ work that way, it probably shouldn't. :) I've updated my answer to qualify my use of "modern" JavaScript to mean "using let and const instead of var" like I should have done in the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

It's a default value for "something" variable.
So if something is not initialized, it will end up containing a blank object (the {}).

in other words something equals (sometging or {}) where undefined evaluates to false so {} is returned.